# Dynamic programming with extremely large inputs

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The problem is to find the path with the minimum number of steps required to reach (m, n) from (1, 1) (if it exists) provided that you can only move in two ways:
(x, y) = (x + y, y) or (x, y) = (x, x + y).

I tried to do this with dynamic programming but m and n can be up to 10^25 so it is not feasible. How can I adapt my solution so that it can work for large inputs? Or is there an alternate method?

Answer (score 5):

Go backwards. Say your goal is (x, y). If x > y, then the last step must have been from (x - y, y); otherwise, the last step must have been from (x, y - x). (If x = y, this location is unreachable.) Working backwards, it's easy to see there's only a single way to reach any reachable goal location, and that path is always obvious.

With that in mind, you can use a minor variation on the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to solve this problem. Each iteration or recursive level represents a number of steps in a given direction, and you can keep track of the number of steps you need along the way.